# Detecting iPad / iPhone using media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

Am working on a project where I need to distinguish between the landscape and portrait modes of iPhone, iPad using media queries. Also, am using iPad 3, iPhone 4s.
As simple and straightforward as this may sound, I am having the hardest time getting this to work.
The closest I got to is this :-

```
@media (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (orientation: portrait) {
/*iPad portrait*/
}

@media (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (orientation: landscape) {
/*iPad landscape*/
}

@media (max-device-width: 480px)
and (orientation: portrait) {
/*iPhone portrait*/
}

@media (max-device-width: 480px)
and (orientation: landscape) {
/*iPhone landscape*/
}
```

But, this does not differentiate between the portrait / landscape modes of the iPhone.
Any clues on what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code that demonstrates functioning queries on an iPhone. It is white in portrait, black in landscape. You can ignore the base64 part, that was just to supply an icon without needing an external file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title>Media</title>
<style>
html,body{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    body { background-color:#FFF; }
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    body { background-color:#000; }
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="fullscreen()">
<span style="color:#000">Portrait</span><span style="color:#FFF">Landscape</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it turns out orientation media query does not work for the iPhones, and works only for the iPads, just found this out and have been looking for some alternate ways to solve this

Comment: I'm not sure where you determined that, it absolutely works in my projects. I'll trim one down as an example and post some sample code

Comment: I found that out online in a few posts discussing the same. For example, http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/the_orientation.html

Comment: Did you give my code a try? Perhaps something changed since that post? It is a few years old.

Comment: I did give the code a try . it is picking up the portrait, but not the landscape, am using an iPhone 4s btw

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, I had tried removing the scripts and without the fullscreen app ! It did not work then. After I added it to home screen and ran it as a full screen app, it works :) Also, am curious to know, is there a way to run it without having to do the full screen app thing ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14496/discussion-between-sanz-and-robot-woods)

Answer (score 1):

I use the following media queries (defining splash images for web apps).  It handles iPhone non-retina and iPhone 4/4s and both non-retina iPad and retina iPad (portrait and landscape).  You can find this at https://github.com/gwilson/iOSWebAppTemplates

```
    <!-- iPhone standard resolution 320x460  (landscape not needed because all web apps start portrait on iPhone) -->
<link  rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-320x460.jpg" media="(device-width: 320px)" />
<!-- iPhone high resolution (retina) 640x920 pixels (landscape not needed because all web apps start portrait on iPhone) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-640x920.jpg" media="(device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
<!-- iPad Portrait 768x1004 -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-768x1004.jpg" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" />
<!-- iPad Landscape 748x1024 (yes, a portrait image but with content rotated 90 degrees - allows 20px for status bar) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-748x1024.jpg" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" />
<!-- iPad retina Portrait 1536x2008 -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-1536x2008.jpg" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
<!-- iPad retina Landscape 1496x2048 (yes, a portrait image but with content rotated 90 degrees - allows 40px for status bar) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-1496x2048.jpg" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */
.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 80.675%;
    padding-left: 1.1625%;
    padding-right: 1.1625%;
    background: #00ff00;
    height: 200px;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 88.2%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0.9%;
    padding-right: 0.9%;
    margin: auto;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100px;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="LayoutDiv1">
    <div class="gridContainer">Welcome to iPad</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```