# Pure CSS Code to detect any version of iPad both portrait and landscape

Tags: css, ipad, responsive-design

I have code that helps filter out CSS only for iPad. It is for 1024x768 resolution.

```
@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {

}
@media all and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height:768px) and (orientation:landscape) {

}
```

I want to ask if this code will work on all iPad versions like iPad 1-4, iPad Mini, iPad Air.

If not, I need pure CSS code that will detect all possible versions of iPad in both portrait and landscape modes. Also make sure that code works for iPad 1-2 and iPad with Retina Display.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839809/detect-iphone-ipad-purely-by-css or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680095/detecting-ipad-iphone-using-media-queries?

Comment: Be aware that you will not be able to detect the iPad mini, since it has the same resolution as any other iPad.

Comment: Will be same code work for iPad 1-2 and iPad with retina display?

Comment: I found this link useful http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are useful CSS Media Queries for iPad and iPad with Retina Display.

**iPad in portrait & landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPad in landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**Retina iPad in portrait**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**iPad 1 & 2 in portrait & landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1){ /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPad 1 & 2 in landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPad 1 & 2 in portrait**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

Ref: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/